# Mat to IplImage crash

Tags: opencv

The camera keeps on crashing when I run my code. Trying to convert cv::mat to IplImage.

```
cv::Mat canvas(320, 240, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255,255,255));

 IplImage test =canvas;

  while(true )
{  

 canvas =cvQueryFrame(capture);
 imgScribble = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&test), 8, 3);

 IplImage* imgYellowThresh1 = GetThresholdedImage1(&test);

cvAdd(&test,imgScribble,&test);

cvShowImage("video", &test);
```

Comment: I have to make the comment that OpenCV wasn't meant to mix its C++ and C API. cv:: is C++, cvFoo() and IplImage*, generally Foo* are C API. Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: `IplImage* test=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)canvas);`

Comment: Okay so in C if I wanted to draw the image to a transparent background, do you know if it's possible like in C++?

Comment: @AndreaF http://docs.opencv.org/genindex.html For basically any C (old) function there is a C++ equivalent. And viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is the only line that uses the C++ API, so I assume you want to use the C API instead     
cv::Mat canvas(320, 240, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255,255,255)); 
//I have used OpenCV for quite a while now and I've always declared IplImage*, and never IplImage. Use it safely as a rule of thumb, * always goes after IplImage
 IplImage test =canvas;
```

This will become:

```
//although why you need to clone a newly created
//blank image is a valid concern
IplImage* canvas = cvCreateImage(....); 
IplImage* test = cvClone(canvas);   
cvZero(test);
//don't forget to release resources at some point
cvReleaseImage(&canvas);
cvReleaseImage(&test);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe if I explain what I want do it, it'll be more clear why I'm making a copy. I'm trying to create a transparent background so that when I add the imgYellowThresh1 image, it'll be on top of this instead of my webcam image.